# Related rates of $y^2-3xy+x^2=25$ given $x$ and $y$ are dependent of $t$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I am given the following problem:

> Two variables $x$ and $y$ are dependent of $t$ and are related
>   according to
>
> $$y^2-3xy+x^2=25$$
>
> If $x$ varies $1$ unit when $x = 0$ then find $\frac{dy}{dt}$ at that
>   specific moment.

What I have so far is

$$
2y \frac{dy}{dt} - 3y \frac{dx}{dt} - 3x \frac{dy}{dt} + 2x \frac{dx}{dt} = 0\\
2y \frac{dy}{dt} - 3y = 0\\
\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{3}{2}
$$

Is that correct? Did I miss something?

Thank you.

Comment: Should that be for  given $ dx/dt =1 $ when $ t=0?$

Comment: @Narasimham $dx/dt = 1$ when $x=0$ actually.

Comment: That looks good. For completeness you should note that at $x=0$ you must have $y=\pm5$, so $y\ne0$ and hence it is legitimate to divide by $y$ to get your final result.